# Why does this function fail to withdraw ether from a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I used the following code which I thought would be able to withdraw any ether that was deposited to the smart contract. Can you help explain why this might not work?

```html
function withdraw() public {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

I am having issues withdrawing the ether and was wondering which part of the code is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: Could you post the entirety of your smart contract along with the code you're using to call the contract's `withdraw()` function?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
 function withdraw(uint amount) public payable{
    require(address(this).balance >= amount);
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);   
}
```

use this code

Comment: OP appears to be looking to withdraw ALL funds from the contract